# How to reference the angular scope of the main (index.html) and another child view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular route defined for the bootstrap main menu items. I have another view (HTML page) that implements isteven multiselection directives. As I understand it (newbie with angular and bootstrap), controllers are activated when routes change.

How can I cause the child view controller to be executed from the parent controller?

**EDIT**

**MAIN HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors and publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="frainversegment" content="!" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
<!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
              document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-15499108-1");
                    pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch (err) { }
        </script>

        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
              google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3982825388677642",
              enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
        </script>
-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#log-in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="create-account-link" href="#accounts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" id="drop-toggle-1" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-aria-haspopup="true" data-aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a id="update-profile" href="#update-profile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="manage-uploads" href="#manage-uploads">Manage uploads</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
<!--
            <div class="google-ad-top">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                        style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
                        data-ad-client="ca-pub-3982825388677642"
                        data-ad-slot="1133448516"></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
-->
        </header>
        <div id="shares">
            <!-- Twitter -->
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Google Plus -->
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Facebook -->
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon">
                <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Reddit (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit">
                <i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- LinkedIn -->
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>

        </div>

        <div>
            <p id="message"></p>
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <footer>
                <div id="copyright">&#169; 2016, Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#update-profile").on("click", function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("create-or-update", "update");
                console.log("session-storage=" + sessionStorage.getItem("create-or-update"))
                $("#create-account-link").trigger("click");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

** MAIN CONTROLLER - JS**

```
    var wtApp = angular.module('wtApp', ['ngRoute'])
    wtApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        // route for the writers page
        .when('/writers', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/writers.html',
            controller: 'writersController'
        })

        // route for the enablers page
        .when('/enablers', {
            templateUrl: 'isteven.html.html',
            controller: 'enablersController'
        })
        // route for privacy/rues
        .when('/privacy', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/privacy.html'
        })
        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })  
        // route for the contact pagefa
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })
        // route for the log-in page
        .when('/log-in', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        // route for the create account
        .when('/accounts', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/accounts.html',
            controller: 'createAccountController'
        })
        // route for manage uploads
        .when('/manage-uploads', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/manage-uploads.html'
        })
    });

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
wtApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.example2model = []; $scope.example2data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}]; $scope.example2settings = {displayProp: 'id'};
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='']").css({color:'#FF5733'});
});

wtApp.controller('writersController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='writers']").css({color:'#FF5733'});
});

wtApp.controller('enablersController', function($scope) {
    $scope.worktype = [
        { icon: "<img src=img/icons/smile-mask.png />", name: "Fiction", ticked: false },
        { icon: "<img src=img/icons/frown-mask.png />", name: "Non-Fiction", ticked: false }
    ];

    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='enablers']").css({color:'#FF5733'});

});
wtApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='about']").css({color:'#FF5733'});
});
wtApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='contact']").css({color:'#FF5733'});
});
wtApp.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='log-in']").css({ color: '#FF5733' });
});
wtApp.controller('createAccountController', function ($scope) {
    resetNavbar();
    $("a[href$='create-account']").css({ color: '#FF5733' });
});
wtApp.controller('ResetPasswordController', function ($scope) {
//    $("a[href$='reset-pwd']").css({ color: '#FF5733' });
});

function resetNavbar() {
    $(".navbar-collapse a").not("a[href='#']").each(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'color': 'black' })
    });
}
```

**CHILD HTML AND JS**

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp" id="myApp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Enablers Form</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/enablers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/isteven-multi-select.css">
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="container center_div">
            <img id="img-enablers" src="#" alt="images" />
            <form id = "form-enablers"  class="form-horizontal well">
                <h1>Enablers</h1>

                <label for="work-type" class="fixed50">Type:</label>
                <p id="work-type"
                    data-isteven-multi-select
                    data-input-model="worktype"
                    data-output-model="outputWorktype"
                    data-button-label="icon name"
                    data-item-label="icon name"
                    data-tick-property="ticked"
                ></p>
                <label for="form-type" class="fixed50">Form:</label>
                <p id="form-type"
                    data-isteven-multi-select
                    data-input-model="formtype"
                    data-output-model="outputFormtype"
                    data-button-label="name"
                    data-item-label="name"
                    data-tick-property="ticked"
                ></p>
                <p>For an explanation of the genres shown here, see <a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genres">List of genres</a><br/></p>
                <label for="genres" class="fixed50">Genres:</label>
                <p id="genres"
                    data-isteven-multi-select
                    data-input-model="genres"
                    data-output-model="outputGenres"
                    data-button-label="name"
                    data-item-label="name"
                    data-tick-property="ticked"
                ></p>
                <label for="accepted-media" class="fixed50">Accepted Media:</label>
                <p id="accepted-media"
                    data-isteven-multi-select
                    data-input-model="acceptedMedia"
                    data-output-model="outputMedia"
                    data-button-label="icon name"
                    data-item-label="icon name"
                    data-tick-property="ticked"
                ></p>
                <p> <label for="special-instructions" class="fixed50">Special Instructions</label>
                    <textarea id ="special-instructions" name="special-instructions"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p>For a limited time, enablers can use this site for <span style="color: #f00; font-weight:bold">FREE</span>. We reserve the right to change this policy without notice.</p>
                <div id="recaptcha-elements"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="enablers-search" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Search</button>
                </div>
                <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <form id="writers-list">
            <p>To request a manuscript, click the checkbox beneath the thumbs-up icon.</p>
            <div id="table-list"></div>
            <div id="main" class="content"></div>
        </form>
        <script src="js/isteven-multi-select.js"></script>
        <script src="js/enablers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/recaptcha.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["isteven-multi-select"]);
            myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.worktype = [
                    { icon: "<img src=img/icons/smile-mask.png />", name: "Fiction", ticked: false },
                    { icon: "<img src=img/icons/frown-mask.png />", name: "Non-Fiction", ticked: false }
                ];
                $scope.formtype = [];
                var data = {};
                data.action = 'multiselect-forms';
                ajax('post', 'php/enablers.php', data, formsSuccess, 'Error retrieving multiselect forms data: ');
                function formsSuccess(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.formtype = eval(data);
                }
                $scope.genres = [];

                data.action = 'multiselect-genres';
                ajax('post', 'php/enablers.php', data, genresSuccess, 'Error retrieving multiselect forms data: ');
                function genresSuccess(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.genres = eval(data);
                }
                $scope.acceptedMedia = [
                    { icon: "<img src=img/home/mail.png />", name: "Mail", ticked: false },
                    { icon: "<img src=img/icons/pdf.png />", name: "PDF File", ticked: false }
                ];
            });

        </script>
    </body>                           
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't. Only inner scopes can execute what is given from their parents.

What you may do is give the inner scope as a parameter for the outer one, it is:

- Create A, the parent scope.
- The parent A, should bootstrap B and put it instance in a variable, like A.contollerB
- Associate the created instance, A.controllerB to the tag scope you need.

Please, say me if it's not enought to help you.

Edit: Code example

Anywhere in main controller initialization, you should pass it`s reference to a variable in $scope:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  this.writersController = $controller('writersController',{$scope: $scope});
```

In the route, reference the variable for wirterController inside the controller you made.